# ValueInjecter map complex types

Tags: c#, mapping, valueinjecter

I am attempting to map these complex types using ValueInjecter but the mapped object all of the properties are null.

**DTO**

```
public class HardwareSettingsDto
{
    public HardwareSettingsDto()
    {
        EmailAlertSettings = new EmailAlertSettingsDto();
        CpuMonitoring = new CpuMonitoringDto();
        NetworkMonitoring = new NetworkMonitoringDto();
    }

    // I wont include the below classes but they contain property types of int, string, bool etc.
    public CpuMonitoringDto CpuMonitoring { get; set; }
    public NetworkMonitoringDto NetworkMonitoring { get; set; }
    public List<DriveSettingsDto> Drives { get; set; }
    public EmailAlertSettingsDto EmailAlertSettings { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class HardwareSettings
{
    public HardwareSettings()
    {
        EmailAlertSettings = new EmailAlertSettings();
        CpuMonitoring = new CpuMonitoring();
        NetworkMonitoring = new NetworkMonitoring();
    }

    public CpuMonitoring CpuMonitoring { get; set; }
    public NetworkMonitoring NetworkMonitoring { get; set; }
    public List<DriveSettings> Drives { get; set; }
    public EmailAlertSettings EmailAlertSettings { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot seem to map them back and forth DTO -> Entity and then Entity -> DTO as everything is null.

Comment: please read this carefully https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @Omu the `Mapper.AddMap` Where should I create the Map? At the beginning of the application lifecycle? Does the `AddMap` stay throughout the application lifecycle OR do I just create the map when I want to use it?

Comment: `Mapper` maps are saved in a static field, you can look at prodinner demo for asp.net mvc sample